# Datagridview NOT loading all records from table

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hello this is still aggravation for me. I loaded a database table with 11 records and then following this the datagridview pops up and loads only 10! Whats wrong?

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT PartNbr, Qty, Price FROM CompBOM  WHERE HeaderCounter LIKE '" & frmHeader.txtAutoNumber.Text & "' AND LabelName LIKE '" & mbLabel & "'", conn)
adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
builder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
dataSet = New DataSet()
conn.Open()
adapter.Fill(dataSet, "CompBOMTable")
conn.Close()
DGView.DataSource = dataSet
DGView.DataMember = "CompBOMTable"
```

Comment: can you check pagination set to 10?

Comment: Maybe not all 11 rows satisfies the `where` condition in the query?

Comment: What is Pagination?!

Comment: Yes all the rows most definitely satisfy the query

Comment: Im using oleDb class; not sqlconnection class. I dont think u can do pagination with ole but maybe u know more